# Django - Get items in many sets

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset

My models:

```
class ItemSet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    item = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

A set includes many items and a item can be in many sets.
So, how to get a list of items when we know the id of a item in some sets but itself?
Please give me some codes. Thank you very much!

**Example:**
We have two sets like this:
(1,2,3,4) and (2,3,5,7,9),
id = 3 then result = (1,2,4,5,7,9). Note: result does not include 3.

Comment: `how to get a list of items when we know the id of a item in some sets but itself`: can you rephrase this sentence and add an example?

Comment: sorry, i've added an exam as you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a **distinct** set of all items from all `ItemSets` which contain a specific `Item`, **excluding** the `Item` itself from the returned set. Does that sound  about right?

**Edit:** Tested.

```
class ItemSet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    items = models.ManyToManyField('Item', related_name='item_sets')
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=100)

# First, get all sets containing the item we're interested in:
item_sets = ItemSet.objects.filter(items__pk=item.pk)
# Next, get all items belonging to those sets, excluding the item we're interested in:
items = Item.objects.filter(item_sets__pk__in=item_sets).exclude(pk=item.pk).distinct()
```

**Note:** This actually executes a single query (using Django 1.2.1), though, this might depend on your database backend. You can examine the generated SQL like so:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> items._as_sql(connection)
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Get all `Item`s in a specific `ItemSet`:

```
set = ItemSet.objects.get(id=99)
items = set.item.all()
```

Get all `ItemSet`s containing a specific `Item`:

```
item = Item.objects.get(id=88)
sets = item.itemset_set.all()
```

For more info - [read](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#making-queries) the [docs](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/many_to_many/).

Comment: Just because I have a large number of the items. I want to choose a best way for queries. Thanks!

Comment: Start off the traditional way. Optimize as necessary. Never prematurely.